# Using MAX7219 Dot Matrix module with Luma.Led on different GPIOs

Tags: pi-4, spi, led

I have a MAX7219 dot matrix module ([this one](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4001131640516.html?pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%21%E2%82%AC%201%2C23%211%2C04%20%E2%82%AC%21%21%21%21%21%40211b600816800122149713962e2ce8%2112000028237000958%21btf&_t=pvid%3A8fa0de3d-e002-48d0-857d-012c6398409c&afTraceInfo=4001131640516__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1680012215&spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.mainProduct&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu)) that I'm trying to run on my Raspberry Pi 4 with the Luma.LED library. Its documentation suggests the following GPIOs/pins be used:

| Board Pin | Name | Remarks | RPi Pin | RPi Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VCC | +5V Power | 2 | 5V |
| 2 | GND | Ground | 6 | GND |
| 3 | DIN | Data In | 19 | GPIO 10 (MOSI) |
| 4 | CS | Chip Select | 24 | GPIO 8 (SPI CE0) |
| 5 | CLK | Clock | 23 | GPIO 11 (SPI CLK) |

However, mine is connected as follows, because I'm also running an epaper on the Raspberry Pi that needs some of the pins:

| Board Pin | Name | Remarks | RPi Pin | RPi Functions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VCC | +5V Power | 4 | 5V |
| 2 | GND | Ground | 14 | GND |
| 3 | DIN | Data In | 38 | GPIO 20 (DIN/MOSI6/MOSI1/GPCLK0) |
| 4 | CS | Chip Select | 12 | GPIO 18 (CLK/CE0N6/CE0N1/PWM0) |
| 5 | CLK | Clock | 40 | GPIO 21 (SCLK6/SCLK1/GPCLK1) |

I had the dot matrix module working in this configuration before but after a reinstall, I can't get it to work anymore. I have a vague memory I needed to change a config file somewhere to make the module work with the different pin, but cannot remember which one or how. Possibly something in /boot/config.txt?

What I've tried:

- Made sure SPI is enabled via *sudo raspi-config* > 3-Interface options > I4-SPI.

Answer (score 0):

After all of this, I finally figured it out thanks to this page: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi#

Just needed to add the following line to */boot/config.txt*:

```
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs
```